# Bootstrap nested columns seems to leave extra space

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

When I do something like this in a row:

```
<div class="col-sm-2">
    <div class="col-sm-10" style="height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6">
</div>
```

there will be a space between col-sm-2 and the col-sm-6 where the nested columns don't fill the entire col-sm-2 width. How do you fix this?

Comment: Change `<div class="col-sm-2">` to `<div class="col-sm-2 row">` and remove `margin: 0px; padding: 0px;` from nested div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a comment, I will answer to give a detailed explanation.

Every `col-` has a padding in the bootstrap css, in order to remove that padding and have nested `col-`s not show that extra padding you have to add the class `row` to the parent div.

So change `<div class="col-sm-2">` to `<div class="col-sm-2 row">` and remove `margin: 0px; padding: 0px;` from nested div.

Hopefully I understood your question correctly.

Working Fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/xp661ow3/

This is how it looks on my end
[image]

Edited to fix some typos

Comment: The issue though now is that the row adds a new row, I want it to be on the same initial row.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you're trying to say. Edit: I think I get it, your screen size might be too small thus activating the media query to change the width of the divs to 100%. @shell Added an image to the answer to show you how it looks on my end.

Answer (score 1):

Because either of this (or both, depend on your intend):

- The nested column use **.col-sm-10**, while to full you should you **.col-sm-12**
- Still not full? Maybe you want use *padding:0* in your **.col-sm-2**